# How can i get the length of empty li elements between to populated li elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple `<li>` elements and they will be populated randomly after loading. For example if I have twelve `<li>` elements and only two of them are populated, how can I get the number of empty `<li>` elements and the populated ones?

This is a test markup, my problem is how can I get the length between populated `<li>`:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li><span>text</span></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><span>text</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please share the code you've tried and HTML markup.

Comment: Provided data is not sufficient to find required length, add HTML code also

Comment: Try `document.querySelector('ul').innerText.length`.

Comment: @vibhor1997a thanks but It will not return me the length of empty li between the populated ones

Comment: @Alex Please explain exactly what do you mean by length in your context.

Comment: @vibhor1997a I have to detect the number of empty elements between the populated ones, maybe I was a little bit hazy, sorry about that

Comment: If you're populating this list dynamically will there only ever be one sequence of empty-elements between populated elements? And what do you want returned? Just the number of empty elements (so in this case 3)? Or do you want the index of the first empty element as well? What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Also, perhaps of relevance: https://jsfiddle.net/sn0a65g7/2/

Comment: @DavidThomas I got the answer from Trương Công Hậu
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope can help you.

```
function getItems() {
    let indexNotEmpty = [];
    $('ul > li').each(function(i, item) {

        if(item.innerText != ''){
            indexNotEmpty.push(i);
        };
    });

  return indexNotEmpty[indexNotEmpty.length-1]-indexNotEmpty[0]-1;
}
```

Comment: Great, this will do the job.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, that I understand what you want but here is an example what I think you want.

```
    <script>

    function getItems() {
       var count = [0,0];

       $("li").each(function() {
       if($(this).text().length != 0)
          count[0]++;
       else
          count[1]++;
       });
       return count;
    }

    var items = getItems();
    // items[0] should return 4
    // items[1] should return 2

    </script>
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: nice code, but this one will return me the number of populated and empty elements. I have to detect the number of empty elements between the populated elements.
And btw item[0] returns 4 and intem[1] returns 2, no worries I got the point, thanks